# What is the relation between Coq's type system CiC and lambda cube?

Tags: coq, type-systems

I read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_cube#Formal_definition and got confused with the relation between CiC and lambda cube.
As far as I understand, CiC extends CoC which is a corner of lambda cube, so rules of lambda cube should be satisfied also in Coq.

For instance, it seems coq accepts (＊,＊). Because the type of `nat -> nat` is `Set` which is the type of the `nat`(the right side one).

But it seems Coq does not accept (□,＊). If it does, then the type of `Set -> nat` has to be `Set`, not `Type`. But Coq's answer to `Check (Set -> nat)` is `Type`.

Have I misunderstood the description on the wiki page?

Comment: "If it does, then the type of `Set -> nat` has to be `Set`" Why exactly? I'm not sure how that follows from Wikipedia's definition of (◻, ∗) as "allows terms to depend on types".

Comment: Perhaps relatedly, Coq is not impredicative (by default), so in that sense, it isn't purely an "extension" of CoC (or anything containing system F).

Comment: @SCappella because AFAIK ◻ is Type and ∗ is Set, so in Set -> nat, s1 is Set and s2 is nat so THE type of (Set -> nat) should be Set which is s2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coq does not have a single untypable □, but a hierarchy of typeable ones. (In particular, □:□ is a rough approximation of one of the typing rules.) So, because of these "universes", Coq does not quite fit the setting of the lambda cube.

As for `Set -> nat` being of type `Set`, it depends on whether `Set` is impredicative. By default, it is predicative, so `Set -> nat` needs to have a type strictly larger than `Set` itself, i.e., `Type`. But you can change `Set` to be impredicative:

```
$ coqtop -impredicative-set
Welcome to Coq 8.11.1 (April 2020)

Coq < Check (Set -> nat).
Set -> nat
     : Set
```